# retrofit integration with hybrid app

Tags: android, retrofit

We are trying to integrate retrofit in our hybrid app , but we are facing some challenges .

For retrofit there is dependent jar  “okhttp jar” . In our hybrid app we are using Cordova Jar .
If we are including okhttp jar there is conflict happening between both of jar as cordova internally includes okhttp jar . We are using 1.3 version of okhttp as “Cordova 3.4” also includes same.

Please let us know if any anybody has experience such kind of scenario and if this can be resolved.

Please share experience that how feasible will be  integration of “volley”  in hybrid app (Cordova lib)

Comment: Have you tried to exclude okhttp jar from the cordova dependency?

Comment: How i can do it ? will it not effect how cordova works

Answer (score 2):

I assume you use `Gradle` to build your project. In that case you can exclude `okhttp` dependency from the `retrofit` module, so your dependency would look like this:

```
compile ('com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.4.0') {
    exclude module: 'okhttp'
}
```